# Dynamic link inside a dynamic PHP table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a dynamic PHP table where I am trying echo one of the table columns as a dynamically generated link.  Presently, the $url variable i have declared is returning null. $row['username'] is returning what it should, so I suspect I have the syntax off for that. I also am having trouble with the syntax on the following line. How do I insert the $row['username'] as the link text?

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='".$url."'> . $row['username'] .  </a>" . "</td>";
```

this present example returns an error, but when I replace it with:

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='".$url."'> blahblahfiller </a>" . "</td>";
```

the page runs, so I know it's my syntax there.

Here is my full code for the table:

```
<?php
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $url = "profilepage.php?name=" + $row['username'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<a href='".$url."'> . $row['username'] .  </a>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $url . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
   }
?>
```

Sincere thanks for any and all help! It means a lot.

Comment: As you can see on the syntax highlighting `$row['username']` is *inside* the string as you never end it. It needs to be added like `gender` and the other `username` (surrounded by `" . $row['username'] . "`)

Comment: Thank you. That worked  great. I would up vote you, but not enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `+` instead of `.` for to concatenate. It should be -

```
$url = "profilepage.php?name=". $row['username'];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. That works great. I assumed that worked like HTML for some reason.

Comment: `HTML` or `JavaScript`?

Comment: yeah, Javascript, haha.